# jQuery using 'this' in a function

Tags: jquery

I've used jQuery to open and close some divs.

The code works fine until I try to use it as a function, where, I think due to context / or scoping issues the `jQuery(this)` that I've been using as a selector doesn't work when executed from a function.

The function is this:

```
  function open_close_sections() {
     if(jQuery('.question').hasClass('open')) {
            jQuery(this).removeClass('open');
            jQuery(this).next().slideUp();             
            }
           else
           { 
             jQuery('.open').not(this).next().slideUp();
             jQuery('.open').not(this).removeClass('open');
             jQuery(this).addClass('open');
             jQuery(this).next().slideDown();
           }

  }
```

and I'm trying to invoke it with

```
jQuery('.question').click(open_close_sections());
```

You can see the code working outside of a function at this pen:
http://codepen.io/amort2000/pen/KVqaqr
and failing to work in a function at this pen:
http://codepen.io/amort2000/pen/YwQNOQ

Comment: As per the linked dupe. jQuery's `click` is expecting a function reference - not the result of calling the function. Remove the parentheses.

Comment: how is this a duplicate of that question??

Comment: You can use `bind` as well to bind the context. Also `jQuery('.question').click(open_close_sections());` should be `jQuery('.question').click(open_close_sections);`

Comment: @lascort How is it *not*?

Comment: The question you marked as being a duplicate of does not address the major issue he's having with scope. I reckon though that after the scope problem is solved he will have to resort to that question. But I don't think that makes it a duplicate

Comment: @lascort There is no issue with scope. jQuery binds the `this` reference to the function automatically. Once the parentheses are removed it works correctly.

Comment: @Juhana let me downvote myself to oblivion

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  function open_close_sections(x) {
    if (jQuery(x).hasClass('open')) {
      jQuery(x).removeClass('open');
      jQuery(x).next().slideUp();
    } else {
      jQuery('.open').not(x).next().slideUp();
      jQuery('.open').not(x).removeClass('open');
      jQuery(x).addClass('open');
      jQuery(x).next().slideDown();
    }

  }
  jQuery('.answer').hide();
  jQuery('.question').click(function () {
    open_close_sections(this)
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot people - especially Rejith. That works brilliantly. Now I'm off to sit quietly with some jQuery tutorials and try to up my game. thanks again,]